# Not able to download npm packages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, npm-install, npm-package

[Help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXoCH.png)

I have tried changing my proxy and registry still the same problem I also reset
my networks my internet is good help .I am also Not able to use any method of installing packages of react for example- npm create vite@latest or cra method

npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-vite failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 122.161.50.108:8080
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'